# Allow whitelist ip address in Azure Network security group

Tags: azure

I have a list IP address that I want to allow access to multi VMs.
First, I attach to 1st VM a NSG A which allows my whitelist IPs on port 22.
Second, I attach to 2nd VM a NSG B which allows my whitelist IPs on port 8888.
In case I have to update whitelist IP, I need to update both 2 NSG A and NSG B.
Are there any way allow me to update only 1 NSG, then other NSG apply it automatically?

in AWS, I can do it by using a SG as Source of other SG. But Azure may have different strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach both VMs to one NSG.
Also, you can attach NSG to network level (if both VMs in one network).
I think you will find the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/network-overview

Comment: Sorry, cause of security, 1st VM can allow to open port 22, but 2nd VM should not allow port 22. So I think it still need to separate 2 NSG for each VM.

Comment: @hoangmnsd in NSG you can modify not only source, but destination as well. So you can open 22 port only for VM1.